# 404 error when using response.sendfile in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have an Express Node.js application. The structure is the following:

```
myapp
  +-- node_modules
  +-- public
         |-- htmls
               |-- myhtml.html
  +-- routes
         |-- index.js
  |-- app.js
```

My `app.js` is as follows:

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
// some stuff...
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/content/:file', routes.plainhtml);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

My `routes/index.js` is as follows:

```
// Some stuff...
exports.plainhtml = function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('/public/htmls/' + req.params.file);
};
```

I open my browser and try to get the following address: `http://localhost:3000/content/myhtml.html` and I get 404 error:

> Express 404 Error: ENOENT, stat '/public/htmls/myhtml.html'

The routing is done and the function is called... the problem is when I try to use `res.sendfile`. What address should I pass there???

What to do?

Comment: Did you try `public/htmls/`?

Comment: It works... but I added the rule in app.js to use /public and not just public... mak would you please post an answer that also explains how routing is performed in Expression/Node.js? And also... who is handling routing here? Node,js or Express? Thankyou

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your express app is in `app.js`.

The `path` parameter for `sendfile` is a relative path. So when you do `res.sendfile('xxx.js')`, express will look for `xxx.js` in the same directory that `app.js` is in.

If `path` starts with a slash `/` it means that it's an absolute path in the file system e.g. `/tmp`.

If you are using relative paths you can also specify the root path:

```
res.sendfile('passwd', { root: '/etc/' });
```

See the [docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendfile).

Comment: This still prints ENOENT: <complete server path> onto the page which leaks unwanted server information to the user when the user requests with a non-existing :file parameter.

Comment: Then check if the file exists.